# How to know if a ComboBox ValueChangeListener is triggered from select or from the user

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

Suposse that I define a ComboBox like this:

```
ComboBox myCombo = new ComboBox();
myCombo.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
    //Some code
});
```

And then, after adding items to the ComboBox I select one:

```
myCombo.select(someItem);
```

Is there any way from witch I can know if the code inside the value change listener is executed because of a calling to `myCombo.select(someItem)` or because the user changes the value of the ComboBox?

Comment: Have you looked for event.getSource()?

Comment: You can/should set a flog before doing the programatic select(...) and then evaluate this in your code. (Or subclass the combobox and nest the logic in there...

Comment: Can you not just call the myCombo.select(someItem); before you add the listener?

Comment: Thank you André, that is a good solution. You should post as an answer.

Comment: It would still be simpler to add the ValueChangeListener after you've problematically selected your initial value.

Comment: Yes, but for my case, I should add the ValueChangeListener when I declare the ComboBox (the select is not for "select" the initial value).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to know if your `//Some code` section is actually being executed or do you want to distinguish if the event was fired either by your code or because the user clicked on an element?

Comment: The second one, I want to know if the event was fired by my code or by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We simply use a flag such as `_internalChange` and we check it in the listener function. Not cool enough but it works :) A reusable solution would be to create a new component.

```
boolean _internalChange = false;

void init(){
  ComboBox myCombo = new ComboBox();
  myCombo.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
    if(_internalChange) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  });
}

void selectMyCombo(Object value){
  _internalChange = true;
  myCombo.select(stuff)
  _internalChange = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is this. If you haven't added the ValueChangeListener when you select the initial value the listener won't get triggered.

```
ComboBox myCombo = new ComboBox();

// add items to the ComboBo

myCombo.select(someItem);

myCombo.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
    //Some code
});
```

Comment: But I need the listener to be triggered when `myCombo.select(someItem)` is called. What I needed is a functionality when the valueChangeListener is triggered by the select and  another when is triggered by the user. André's solution maybe is not the best or cleaner solution but it worked for me.